# Is Cookies the best way?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, joomla

I am using Joomla, and there are 2 Sections/Branches, when the user lands on the home page they will be asked where they wan to go to.

If they choose Section A i want the browser to remember their choice for future, however if they decide for some reason to visit Section B later, i want the browser to replace the Section A with B so that in future B will be remembered.

Is using cookies the right way, if so how could this be done, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would use cookies set by server in HTTP reply. Why not? It doesn't rely on enabled JavaScript, that's an advantage. You could implement additional storage technics to catch the case, that the browser cleans up even long life cookies at the end of session.

Comment: However, cleaning up cookies is a user decision, which should indicate, that one doesn't like to remember such things. We should not try to force a user against his desire.

Answer (score 0):

Today the moist preferred way is storing  inside a localstorage  and not inside cookie's

because cookies are sent vs every request and storage is not.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Also you can pick one of the libs from [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/9-javascript-libraries-working-with-local-storage/)

And you can use [modernizer](https://modernizr.com/) to be compliant with the old browsers version.

Answer (score 0):

```
Setcookie("path", "A", 3600*31*365); // Set cookie for about a year.
Echo $_cookie["path"]; // Read cookie 
Setcookie("path", "B", 3600*31*365); // Replace the cookie with path B.
```

Answer (score 0):

If both section/branches are in same domain (or subdomains) cookies are a good way, but local storage can be a good option too.

The following link can help you to use cookies in Joomla http://blog.tormix.com/joomla/set-and-get-cookies-in-joomla-cms/